50 Hz to 60 Hz converter for vintage clock
I know this question has been asked many times before, but I'm specifically looking for suggestions on how to design a circuit to accomplish this, rather than 'where can you buy' or 'is it ok to...' etc.
I have a vintage mains-powered clock that works off 120 V, 60 Hz, and I would like to use it in the UK. My initial idea is to start with a suitable DC PSU and then use a resonant LC circuit, tuned to approximately 60 Hz, and driven by an output of e.g. an ATmega328 to both generate the required 60 Hz and to provide the 120 V output. I intend to use a control loop to limit the AC output to around 120 V and monitor the incoming 50 Hz mains frequency to use as a timing reference.
So e.g. to use the ATmega 'analog' (actually PWM) outputs, via (probably) an NPN/PNP push-pull driver to the L (or C) of the LC tuned circuit, the other end of which is grounded.
I'm fairly sure this should work, but since this is a common use-case (and indeed you can buy devices to do this), is there a better solution?
The clock has a label on it saying '120 V, 60 Hz, 2.5W'.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How do you know the clock uses the 60Hz mains as timing reference, have you tried it at 120V 50Hz? If it does use mains, is there a 50Hz/60Hz selector inside? Why not simply generate a 50 Hz sine wave e.g at 6VAC and use a 6VAC to 120VAC transformer? Or bypass the clock internal transformer? Or put a circuit inside the clock that changes the mains cycle detection? Do you want to keep the clock intact? Can you simply buy a 60Hz inverter?

Why not to generate 60Hz according mains 50Hz? Just sense the zero crosses of 50 and calibrate the generated 60.

How about an mp3-player with a very long 60 Hz track put on repeat, a tiny amplifier and a suitable transformer to get to 120 V?

Try a PLL running at 3kHz upscaled from 50Hz then divide by 50.

a small photo of your clock would help.

It's a 'flip clock', so yes, driven by an ac motor. Yes, I would like to keep the clock intact. Using a zero-crossing detector is essentially what I meant by "monitor the incoming 50 Hz mains frequency to use as a timing reference". The mains frequency will be accurate, unless there is a power outage. A GPS is fine if there is a reasonable signal but I don't think that can be guaranteed. An MSF receiver would be a better option IMO.
I did consider a transformer but thought a reasonant circuit might be less bulky.

Before you get going, try building a 60 Hz resonant circuit.  An entertaining learning experience is assured.  Also the result won't necessarily be stable enough for time keeping.

Right but the intention is to drive the LC circuit with a 60Hz synthesized sine wave. The resonance is used to generate the high voltage, in place of a transformer. The LC needs to be approximately the right frequency (and I'm expecting to have to manually tune it) but any error wll only result in a lower voltage output and not change the frequency at all.

I'm assuming that this clock is a analogue clock driven by a synchronous ac motor.
Use the microcontroller to generate a low voltage sine wave using an H-bridge driven by the PWM controller. This could easily generate a low voltage (say 12 V) sine wave at 60 Hz. Make sure you use a decent timebase for the controller as this will set the long term accuracy of the clock. The power supply for this could be a "wall wart."
Use a mains transformer in reverse to convert the low voltage ac to 120 Vac to power your clock.

Sounds like a fun little project.
@DDuck has already covered some of the hardware design, which should look something like this:

The key items are a zero-cross detector for the 50 Hz AC line, and an H-bridge driver to drive the output transformer through a low-pass filter. I would not try to use any resonant circuits, as these tend to be highly sensitive to loading, etc.
In software, you need to create the equivalent of a PLL to convert the 50 Hz line frequency reference to 60 Hz. The software architecture looks something like this:

The idea is to use one of the MCU's timers to generate a relatively high-frequency interrupt — I show 10 kHz, but any convenient value in that general range would do. This interrupt drives a "Numerically-Controlled Oscillator" (NCO), which is just a matter of adding a "frequency" variable to a "phase" accumulator each time the interrupt occurs, and then using the high bits of the phase value to index a wave table that defines your PWM outputs.
The output frequency of the NCO will depend on the interrupt frequency \$F_{int}\$, the number of bits in the phase accumulator \$N\$ and the value of \$freq\$:
$$F_{NCO} = F_{int}\frac{freq}{2^N}$$
So if you want to produce a 60 Hz waveform, just solve for \$freq\$.
Let's assume a 16-bit accumulator.
$$freq = F_{NCO}\frac{2^N}{F_{int}} = 60\frac{2^{16}}{10000} = 393.216$$
Since \$freq\$ needs to be an integer, we'll end up dithering between the values 393 and 394.
The high 8 bits of the phase accumulator will count from 0 to 255, completing cycles at a 60 Hz rate,
and this can be used to index the wave table to update the PWM outputs to the H-bridge. (Finding the values to put in the table is left as an exercise for the reader.)
The zero-cross detector will be giving you interrupts at 50 or 100 Hz, depending on exactly how you do it. In the interrupt handler, you'll count to 5 or 10, and perform an update of the NCO's frequency at a rate of 10 Hz (the greatest common divisor between the two frequencies).
The idea of the PLL is that you want the NCO phase value to be as close to zero as possible each time you do one of these updates.
If the NCO is running fast, the phase will be a positive value, and if it is running slow, it will be a negative value.
So the simplest way to do this is to simply look at the sign (highest bit) of the phase accumulator.
If it is 0 (positive), you want to slow the NCO down, so set \$freq\$ to 393.
If it is 1 (negative), you want to speed up the NCO, so set \$freq\$ to 394.
This automatically creates the dithering mentioned above.
The output frequency will be either 59.967 or 60.120 Hz for six cycles at a time, resulting in a phase jitter of about 4° peak-to-peak, which will be smoothed out by the clock motor's rotational inertia.

There are more sophisticated ways to go about this, depending on the level of performance and features you're looking for.
I also want to point out that you could turn your vintage clock into an "atomic clock" by simply using the 1 PPS output of a GPS receiver module in place of your line frequency input and making the corresponding tweaks to the external interrupt handler.

Thanks. An interesting approach. I already intended to use the 50Hz mains input so it's just a question of whether to directly synthesize a 60Hz signal or use a free-running VCO (or NCO as you suggest) in a PLL. I can see there might be advantages in a separate oscillator but I will have to experiment.
Yes, an LC circuit will be very sensitive to loading, hence the use of a control loop to maintain 120V.

I'm curious -- what do you mean when you say "directly synthesize"?
